# Gammu cannot detect my modem

Tags: sms, gammu

I want to use gammu for sending sms. 
I have problem when want to identify the phone from gammu utility

Environment used:
 - openSUSE 12.3 32-bit
 - Gammu version 1.32.0 built 09:27 on Aug 10 2012 using GCC 4.7

```
> gammu -f /var/log/gammulog identify
```

> **No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected.**

I make sure my modem is connected to my laptop

```
> lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 019: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b3bb Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
```

Then I check using this command to make sure the modem is detected

```
> ls /dev/serial/by-id -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct 31 11:16 usb-HSDPA_USB_Modem_HSDPA_USB_Modem-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct 31 11:16 usb-HSDPA_USB_Modem_HSDPA_USB_Modem-if01-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct 31 11:16 usb-HSDPA_USB_Modem_HSDPA_USB_Modem-if02-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Oct 31 11:16 usb-HSDPA_USB_Modem_HSDPA_USB_Modem-if03-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB3
```

When call the **gammu-detect**

```
[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
name = Phone on USB serial port HSDPA_USB_Modem HSDPA_USB_Modem
connection = at

[gammu1]
device = /dev/ttyUSB1
name = Phone on USB serial port HSDPA_USB_Modem HSDPA_USB_Modem
connection = at

[gammu2]
device = /dev/ttyUSB2
name = Phone on USB serial port HSDPA_USB_Modem HSDPA_USB_Modem
connection = at

[gammu3]
device = /dev/ttyUSB3
name = Phone on USB serial port HSDPA_USB_Modem HSDPA_USB_Modem
connection = at

[gammu4]
device = /dev/ttyS0
name = Phone on serial port 0
connection = at

[gammu5]
device = /dev/ttyS1
name = Phone on serial port 1
connection = at

[gammu6]
device = /dev/ttyS2
name = Phone on serial port 2
connection = at

[gammu7]
device = /dev/ttyS3
name = Phone on serial port 3
connection = at

[gammu8]
device = /dev/ttyS4
name = Phone on serial port 4
connection = at

[gammu9]
device = /dev/ttyS5
name = Phone on serial port 5
connection = at

[gammu10]
device = /dev/ttyS6
name = Phone on serial port 6
connection = at

[gammu11]
device = /dev/ttyS7
name = Phone on serial port 7
connection = at

opening socket: No such device
```

Here is the gammu-config, placed in **/etc/gammurc**

```
[gammu]
port = /dev/ttyUSB0
connection = at115200
logformat = textall
```

I really stuck, don't know what's wrong
Even when using wammu (GUI version), to detect phones

```
Wammu is now searching for phone:
Checking /dev/ttyUSB0 - ['at19200', 'at115200', 'fbusdlr3', 'fbus', 'mbus', 'fbuspl2303']
Checking /dev/ttyUSB1 - ['at19200', 'at115200', 'fbusdlr3', 'fbus', 'mbus', 'fbuspl2303']
Checking /dev/ttyUSB2 - ['at19200', 'at115200', 'fbusdlr3', 'fbus', 'mbus', 'fbuspl2303']
Checking /dev/ttyUSB3 - ['at19200', 'at115200', 'fbusdlr3', 'fbus', 'mbus', 'fbuspl2303']
Finished /dev/ttyUSB2 - ['at19200', 'at115200', 'fbusdlr3', 'fbus', 'mbus', 'fbuspl2303']
Finished /dev/ttyUSB0 - ['at19200', 'at115200', 'fbusdlr3', 'fbus', 'mbus', 'fbuspl2303']
Finished /dev/ttyUSB3 - ['at19200', 'at115200', 'fbusdlr3', 'fbus', 'mbus', 'fbuspl2303']
Finished /dev/ttyUSB1 - ['at19200', 'at115200', 'fbusdlr3', 'fbus', 'mbus', 'fbuspl2303']
All finished, found 0 phones
No phone has been found!
```

Thanks

**Updated**

Here is add some log that happen when I specify the log file

```
> tail -f gammu.log 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: [Gammu            - 1.32.0 built 09:27 Aug 10 2012 using GCC 4.7]
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: [Connection       - "at"]
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: [Connection index - 0]
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: [Model type       - ""]
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: [Device           - "/dev/ttyUSB0"]
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: [Running on       - Linux, kernel 3.7.10-1.16-desktop (#1 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 31 20:21:23 UTC 2013 (97c14ba))]
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is up, CAR is up, CTS is up
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Setting speed to 19200
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: [Module           - "auto"]
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Escaping SMS mode
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: 1 "OK"
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Checking line: OK
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: AT reply state: 1
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Enabling echo
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: 1 "OK"
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: Checking line: OK
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: AT reply state: 1
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: Trying Motorola mode switch
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: 1 "ERROR"
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: Checking line: ERROR
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: AT reply state: 3
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: Frame not request now. If you can, please report it (see <http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/>). Thank you
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: LAST SENT frame type 0x00/length 10
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: 41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x7/7
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: 45E|52R|52R|4FO|52R|0D |0A                                      ERROR..         
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: Seems not to be supported
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: Enabling CME errors
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: 1 "OK"
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: Checking line: OK
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: AT reply state: 1
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: Frame not request now. If you can, please report it (see <http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/>). Thank you
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: LAST SENT frame type 0x00/length 10
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.      
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x4/4
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: 4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:17: 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: 1 "OK"
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: Checking line: OK
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: AT reply state: 1
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: Frame not request now. If you can, please report it (see <http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/>). Thank you
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: LAST SENT frame type 0x00/length 10
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+CMEE=2.      
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x4/4
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: 4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:19: 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: CME errors could not be enabled, some error types won't be detected.
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: 1 "+CSCS: "IRA""
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: 2 "OK"
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: Checking line: OK
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: AT reply state: 1
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: UNKNOWN frame. If you can, please report it (see <http://wammu.eu/support/bugs/>). Thank you
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: LAST SENT frame type 0x00/length 9
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: RECEIVED frame type 0x00/length 0x14/20
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: 2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3A:|20 |22"|49I|52R|41A|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A  +CSCS: "IRA"....
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: 4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:21: 
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:23: Init:GSM_TryGetModel failed with error TIMEOUT[14]: No response in specified timeout. Probably phone not connected.
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:23: [Terminating]
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:23: [Closing]
```

In the beginning part everything is OK

We i look more details in this part everything is success

```
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Sending simple AT command to wake up     some devices
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: 1 "OK"
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Checking line: OK
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: AT reply state: 1
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:14: Enabling echo
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: 1 "OK"
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: Checking line: OK
Thu 2013/10/31 11:55:15: AT reply state: 1
```

Error occured in this part. It's like detecting this is Motorola, but I'm using **Huawei E169**

```
Thu 2013/10/31 14:13:16: Trying Motorola mode switch
Thu 2013/10/31 14:13:16: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Thu 2013/10/31 14:13:16: 41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
Thu 2013/10/31 14:13:16: 1 "ERROR"
Thu 2013/10/31 14:13:16: Checking line: ERROR
```

**Update**

I try to use other modem ZTE MF288, and it works just fine.
Still don't know how to configure Huawei E169

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the Huawei E169 too, but I have only 3 Ports (ttyUSB0, ttyUSB1, ttyUSB2).
Bought it in Germany, using Ubuntu 13.10 with gammu 1.33.0.

Works fine for me when I use the highest port (ttyUSB2).

```
 -> gammu identify
Gerät               : /dev/ttyUSB2
Hersteller           : Huawei
Modell               : E169 (E169)
Firmware             : 11.314.13.00.264
```

It could also be possible the device is in Storage-Mode and you need to switch it to "phone-mode".

Comment: What OS are you using? I've in the past never got identified but I tried Ubuntu 11.10 instead of Debian Wheezy latest. and never switched from it. It has to do with some Kernel issue.

Comment: How can you switch from Storage-Mode to Phone-Mode?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of information in the output but the key output appears to be.
"Seems to not be supported" 
Even though gammu connects to your phone it may not be able to connect to the SMS commands.

Check here for a list of supported phones. http://wammu.eu/phones it appears that your phone is listed.
You may need to set the model  in your .gammurc file. Like this model = E169